# Retriving empty child nodes from root node

Tags: excel, vba, xml-parsing

I have stumbled upon a problem in parsing a xml file from vba & storing to text. I have tried many ways from MSDN but cannot get the empty nodes (i.e) the nodes that are null. For Example my code ignores the empty node which I need. i know its null but I want to print the node value as null.

I have tried with XMLDOM in excel vba but couldnot print it out to the file

This is my xml file.

```html
<Config>
 <Location>
  <Transmit>[0, 1000] s, precision: 10^-1 s</Transmit>
  <Time>[0, 1000] s, precision: 10^-1 s</Time>
 </Location>
 <Maximum_Speed>[0, 180] km.h^-1, precision: 10^-2 m.s^-1</Maximum_Speed>
 <Location2>
  <Time>[0, 1000] s, precision: 10^-1 s</Time>
  <Stop_Duration>[0, 1000] s, precision: 10^-1 s</Stop_Duration>
  <Authorized_Location/>
 </Location2>
</Config>
```

Here's my Excel VBA code

```
Sub Retrive_data_from_xml()
Dim myFile As String
On Error Resume Next
myFile = "C:\Users\Subhra\Desktop\file.txt"
Open myFile For Output As #1
Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False
If xmlDoc.Load("C:\Users\Subhra\Desktop\config.xml") Then
   Display_Values_with_Variables xmlDoc.ChildNodes, 0
End If
Close #1
End Sub

Function Display_Values_with_Variables(ByRef Nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, ByVal spaces As Integer)
   Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
   spaces = spaces + 1
   For Each xNode In Nodes
      If xNode.NodeType = NODE_TEXT Then
         Print #1, Space(spaces) & "/" & xNode.ParentNode.nodeName & ":" & xNode.NodeValue
    End If
      If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
            Print #1, xNode.ParentNode.nodeName
            Display_Values_with_Variables xNode.ChildNodes, spaces
      End If
   Next xNode
End Function
```

I want the Authorized_Location to be printed as **Authorized_Location:Null** but the code ignores the "Authorized_Location". I m referencing MSXML 6.0

Comment: You're only processing text nodes - why not focus on `NODE_ELEMENT` instead?  That way you're not skipping empty elements.

Comment: Hi Tim.. thanks but I have tried that too.. But still unable to find the node. Could you please post a snippet of code.